# Starling Feathers tilerow clickable

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am making a data view based off tileRow layout and I will have 3-5 columns

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
---------------------------------------
row1-1   row1-2   row1-3   row1-4
row2-1   row2-2   row2-3   row2-4
```

etc

At the moment I have set it up to use a for loop to create the items and set the width of each item 1/4 the total size of the container and this works great filling up an entire row with 4 quads so really the layout is like:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
---------------------------------------
tile1   tile2   tile3   tile4
tile5   tile6   tile7   tile8
```

I want to add an event listener to trigger a function when a row is clicked. I am assuming I wont be able to really do this because each row is made up of 4 separate tiles.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired effect or should I just add a fifth column with a button that is clickable?

I can't really use the list as I need multiple columns.

Comment: I don't really see the problem with adding the click handlers to the elements in the row? are you concerned with gaps between the columns/tiles not being clickable?  Or are you concerned with having 4 click handlers registered for each row?

Comment: I guess my concern is how to pass tile1, tile2, tile3 and tile4 (in this example) to the handler with click either tile. Would there be any performance issues if there were 100 rows each with a button?

Comment: Well not necessarily from the handlers themselves, if you're not familiar with object pooling or as it's known in the flex world item renderer recycling, you'll probably want to use or implement something along those lines.  You should be able to modify the data in advance so the click dispatched from any of those elements will be able to determine the row by looking at the data currently assigned to the "DisplayObject" er whatever it is in Starling.  Performance will be an issue with regard to updating position and whatnot with so many rows regardless of making this column division.

Comment: What you'll want to do is basically figure out (ideally in code at run-time) how many will fit on screen, create just that plus 1 or 2 to be ready off screen, as the user scrolls you slide them up and as they go off screen you put them back into the pool of re-usable ones, when you need a new one for the bottom of the list you just pull one from the pool of free and ready to go renderers. I assume Starling has things to help with this, but not an expert there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new Sprite which represents a row.
Take the rowSprite from a pool, and add the items for each row into it.  Then you can put a click handler on the row, and grab the children of the currentTarget of the event.